# Button and List interaction modifications

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to remove the "sectionStyle" for my `List` rows. In order to achieve a tableview-like view, you would write the following:

```swift
List(items, id: \.id) { item in
  ItemRow(with: item)
}
```

If you want to interpret tap events on each row, you would wrap the `ItemRow` into a `Button`:

```swift
List(items, id: \.id) { item in
  Button(action: rowTapped) { 
    ItemRow(item: item)
  }
}
```

The interesting part is that when the `List` knows about the `Button`, it will automatically give a selection animation like tableView's `selectionStyle`. For my application, I'd like to not have that. Is there a way to set the "selectionStyle" for the `List` to "none"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of List behaviours, that I haven't been able to alter.  It's quite easy to build your own list though if you have specific needs different than the system List view. Here's a simple example that I've used.

```
struct MyListView:View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                VStack {
                    Button(action: self.rowTapped) {
                        ItemRow(item: item)
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
    func rowTapped() {
        print("rowTapped")
    }
}

struct ItemRow:View {
    var item:Item

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Spacer()            // force text to left justify
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to achieve the `addRow` / `removeRow` / `performBatchUpdates` animation when the datasource changes? I tried using `ForEach`, but that came with the drawback of not having the nice diff animations.

Comment: If you don't need vertical scrolling,  the .animation(.spring()) modifier applied to a VStack that contains the list seems to generate a similar list animation. There are so many List related issues in Beta 6 and earlier, I'm planning to wait until a future beta.

Comment: Also noticed that `ForEach` doesn't handle cell reuse for you, so long lists can be crippling to memory and block the main thread. 

I tried using 3000 cells and they were all loaded into memory at once. This big rendering pass caused a block on the main thread for several seconds and frame drops during scrolling.

Do you have any tips on how to alleviate that?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of. The List view also suffers serious performance issues for large datasets (500+) if the list is dynamically filtered. In one of my apps, a list of 900 items loads quickly, but if filtered down to 30 items or so, it can take many seconds to update. I think we need to wait until this gets better fleshed out in future updates.